# How do I create a custom voice, and can its tone be changed?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In 'Way Of The Nether' and other mini games a voice comes on and says something like "you'll never save your precious mayor". How do I define my own voice and include it in my game?

I've tried /say /tell /w /whisper but nothing seems to work

Pocket Edition version 1.16.40

Comment: Which edition and version of Minecraft?

Comment: Pocket edition version 1.16.40 for ipad

Answer (score 3):

Voices cannot be generated in vanilla Minecraft. They are custom sounds added by mods.

All the commands you tried are for printing messages in the chat. `/playsound` is the only command that can play sounds, and it can only play predefined sounds. You will need to add your own voice as a custom sound using add-ons.

I'm not much of an expert in modding Minecraft, so I'm not the right person to ask for the job. Check out info on [add-ons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Add-on) if you want to explore this path further, or you can wait for the next answer from a more experienced Minecraft modder.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, first I recomend going to minecraft.net/en-us/add-ons and downloading the “vanilla resource pack”. Then you can do two things. One thing you can do is change a vanilla sound to an OGG file. You cha find a tutorial on this online. Or you can actually create entirely new sounds with just resource packs and then use /playsound to play it. I’m not gonna explain the new sound one because it takes multiple JSON files to write and you *might?* be able to find a tutorial but you might not. I recomend the first approach that should be pretty easy.